# Selection in NavigationLink is not working

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code for my **iPad** app:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selectionIndex: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<5) { tag in
                    NavigationLink("Link \(tag)", destination: DetailView(name: "View \(tag)"), tag: tag, selection: self.$selectionIndex)
                        .foregroundColor((self.selectionIndex ?? 0) == tag ? Color.red : Color.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.name)
    }
}
```

Pressing the links works perfectly and also it changes the DetailView. I try to highlight the selected button, therefore I save the selectionIndex.

Unfortunately the selectionIndex sometimes resets to 0. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Wrapping the `NavigationLink` into a `List` shows the problematic better, as the List has it's own selection (this selection stays, but my own `var selectionIndex` resets).

```
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<5) { tag in
                    NavigationLink("Link \(tag)", destination: DetailView(name: "View \(tag)"), tag: tag, selection: self.$selectionIndex)
                        .foregroundColor((self.selectionIndex ?? 0) == tag ? Color.red : Color.black)
                }
            }
        }
```

See this screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this of course looks like a bug, but they do what they documented - show destination of selected tag, no more. Anyway, probably worth submitting feedback.

Here is a working workaround. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

```
@State var selectionIndex: Int? = nil
@State var highlighted: Int? = nil       // << explicit !!
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<5) { tag in
                NavigationLink("Link \(tag)", destination:
                    PadDetailView(name: "View \(tag)").onAppear { self.highlighted = tag },
                        tag: tag, selection: self.$selectionIndex)
                    .foregroundColor(self.highlighted == tag ? Color.red : Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```