# Get enum Publisher with Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

How can I get a Publisher for an enum value in Combine?

I want to get notified when a enum property get updated to process the value using combine and create a new Publisher for the elaborated value.

I created a working sample of what I want using hardcoded strings for tags &co. that you can find here https://gist.github.com/alessionossa/543a18a55423d98fc415be9edebbddb5 . In this sample I can simply use `highlightedPanel` without any Combine code, but in my real project there is a more complex logic that requires Combine to be used. Now I want to accomplish this using enums to identify NavigationLinks.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

    enum SectionPane: Equatable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {

        case servers
        case snippets

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .servers:
                return "server"
            case .snippets:
                return "snippet"
            }
        }

        var id: SectionPane { self }
    }

    @State var selectedPane: SectionPane? = nil

    // BUG workaround, suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003652/selection-in-navigationlink-is-not-working
    @State var highlightedPane: SectionPane? = nil

    // Subscribe to highlightedPane update to update active var
    private var isActivePublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        // SPOILER: Value of type 'ContentView.SectionPane' has no member 'publisher'
        return highlightedPane?.publisher
            .map { $0.description }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher() ??
                Just("").eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    @State private var active: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // Current selection label
                Text("Selected: \(active)")

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("first view").onAppear{ self.highlightedPane = SectionPane.servers }, tag: SectionPane.servers, selection: $selectedPane) {
                    Text("First")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("second view").onAppear{ self.highlightedPane = SectionPane.snippets }, tag: SectionPane.snippets, selection: $selectedPane) {
                    Text("Second")
                }

                Spacer()
            }.onReceive(isActivePublisher, perform: { selection in
                self.active = selection
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about to make world simpler, like below...

```
enum SectionPane: Equatable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {

    case servers
    case snippets

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .servers:
            return "server"
        case .snippets:
            return "snippet"
        }
    }

    var id: SectionPane { self }
}

class SectionPaneViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var highlightedPane: SectionPane? = nil
    @Published var selectedPane: SectionPane? = nil
}

struct TestEnumPublisher: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = SectionPaneViewModel()

    @State private var active: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // Current selection label
                Text("Selected: \(active)")

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("first view").onAppear{ self.vm.highlightedPane = .servers },
                            tag: SectionPane.servers, selection: $vm.selectedPane) {
                    Text("First")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("second view").onAppear{ self.vm.highlightedPane = .snippets },
                            tag: SectionPane.snippets, selection: $vm.selectedPane) {
                    Text("Second")
                }

                Spacer()
            }.onReceive(vm.$selectedPane, perform: { selection in
                self.active = selection?.description ?? "none"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work fine also in my project, where all the Combine logic happens in a subview, so I have to pass `_vm` to the subview. 
It is annoying that I have to wrap enum property inside an ObservableObject to get a publisher of their value